# Google Slides - programmatically Get Publish to Web Link

Tags: google-drive-api, google-slides-api

Is there a way to "**Publish to the Web...**" a Google Slides presentation **programmatically**?

[image]

Unlike Sheets, Slides takes in additional parameters for publishing. I am trying to figure out how to push the presentation programmatically and get the published URL for use in my application.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found publishing feature using [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/). For this, you may want to [file a feature request](https://developers.google.com/slides/support#missing_features).

Using Google Drive API, you may want to check [Publishing revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions#publishing_revisions),

> For Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides you can publish any revision to the web by setting the `published` property. If the file is created in a G Suite domain, the `publishedOutsideDomain` property indicates whether the revision is accessible by anyone or if it is restricted to users of the domain.

Watch the [video](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions#tips_and_tricks) of Google engineer discussing related tips and tricks for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Teyam. This greatly helped. Google Drive API has a generic updateRevisions method, where I had to pass published=true & publishedOutsideDomain=true to make it publish to web.

Comment: @Bhuvan could you write that up as an answer? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @Bhuvan how did you get the embed link after setting the published parameter to true? I tried to get both the revision and file but the published parameter only returns the boolean value (as it should). Do the API create a new parameter with the embed url?

Comment: I used got the document link.. and manipulated the URL to form the final published link. Get an embed link from the UI. Get the document Id programmatically and replace it in the link you got form embed slide wizard. It is working for now. Fingers Crossed.

Comment: Same here. I used `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${id}/preview` to embed the google slide content, it seems work for me. But I am not sure this is a good practice. Would love to hear if some has better solution.

Comment: Instead of the `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/$ID/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000` embed url which has a different `$ID` than the main presentation url id you can use `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/$ID/present` where `$ID` is the same as the main presentation url

Comment: @Tim this only works if the slide is publicly accessible to the world (it does not have to be published however).

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions from google drive API creating a permission with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create including in request_body the attributes "role":"reader", "type":"anyone", "allowFileDiscovery": false ( getting a "anyoneWithLink" id permission)
and setting the head revision (the last) to published with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions including in request body the attibutes `"published": true, "publishAuto": true, "publishedOutsideDomain": true,`